# display historical map without georeferencing?

Tags: raster, georeferencing

I have a historical map of Rome that was published as 46 separate sheets. I'd like to scan these sheets, mosaic them together, and display them as a single map. I've tried to georeference a few of the scanned sheets and it turns out that the original map is distorted with respect to actual geography, so georeferencing the sheets results in the sheets overlapping or being skewed. I am not interested in projecting the historical map onto a basemap, just stitching them together. Is there a way to mosaic these images without georeferencing, or a way of georeferencing them without causing distortion?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: if you're not concerned about actual location, you could just reference them to each other (load one, then add the next referenced to the first etc.).  Or perhaps just load it in an image editor and line them up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to mosaic without georeferencing is to use an image processor rather than a GIS.  For instance in GIMP do the following (photoshop has similar tools):

1. Open all your images as layers (not individually).
2. Expand the image size to match the total mosaic size
3. Turn on view grid and set the grid size to equal the dimensions of one of your images (assuming they are all the same size) and turn on snap to grid
4. Select each layer in turn (sometimes helps to turn off the display of the others) and drag into place (it will snap exactly if you turned snapping to grid on).
5. Flatten image and do any other post processing such as cleaning/enhancing etc and save.

Now switch to your gis and georeference the mosaiced image.